# For which $b,c \in (1,\infty) \subset \Bbb{R} $ is $\Theta(e^{log_b(n)})=\Theta(e^{log_c(n)})$?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

For which $b,c \in (1,\infty) \subset \Bbb{R} $ is $\Theta(e^{log_b(n)})=\Theta(e^{log_c(n)})$ ?

I was thinking obviously for $b=c$ the claim is true. By simplifying a bit i got
$\Theta(e^{ln(n)}/e^{ln (b)})$ where $e^{ln(b)}$ is a constant so it can be removed. So $\Theta(e^{log_b(n)})=$$\Theta(e^{ln(n)})=\Theta(n)$ So apparently it is true for all $b,c$ . Am i right ?

Comment: No, it's $\exp \frac{\ln n}{\ln b}$, not $\frac{\exp \ln n}{\exp \ln b}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you, silly mistake

Comment: @DanielFischer Can i get some hint on how to continue?

Comment: Use $\exp (\gamma\ln n) = n^{\gamma}$.

Comment: So apparently it equals $\Theta (n^{1/ln(b)})$ so it is only true for   all $b=c$  ?

Comment: Yup, $b = c$ and nothing else.

Comment: Thank you, you can add this as an answer and ill accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $\log_b n = \frac{\ln n}{\ln b}$ and $e^{\gamma \ln n} = n^{\gamma}$, we find

$$\Theta(e^{\log_b n}) = \Theta(n^{1/\ln b})\,.$$

Since $\Theta(n^{\beta}) = \Theta(n^{\gamma})$ if and only if $\beta = \gamma$, it follows that

$$\Theta(e^{\log_b n}) = \Theta(e^{\log_c n}) \iff b = c\,.$$